# Animation library for XNA

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, animation

I'm looking at implementing an existing XNA Animation library into my [engine](http://projectvanquish.codeplex.com).  I would ideally like to be able to use BVH animations, but I'm not sure on which is a good library to work with.  Any ideas?

Comment: This is a "what technology to use" question, please refresh yourself on the [FAQ] to learn what types of questions to ask here.